# delete row when click on hyperlink of delete

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, apex-param

row not delete when click on delete hyperlink what i'm doing wrong.

apex class

```
public class DeleteEditController{
public List<Stud__c> contacts{get;set;}
public String conId{get;set;}

public DeleteEditController(){
    contacts = new List<Stud__c>([Select Id, Name__c, Email_Address__c from Stud__c]);

}

public PageReference remove(){
    integer index = 0;
    for(Stud__c con : contacts){
        if(con.Id == conId){
            contacts.remove(index);
            break;
        }
        index ++ ;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

VFPAge

```
<apex:page controller="DeleteEditController">
<apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="Remove" action="{!remove}" rendered="rm">
       <apex:param name="arg" value="" assignTo="{!conId}"/>
       </apex:actionFunction>
         <apex:pageBlock id="rm">
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!contacts}" var="co">
          <apex:column headerValue="Delete Record">
          <a href="#" onClick="remove('{!co.Id}');">Delete</a></apex:column>
         <apex:column value="{!co.Name__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!co.Email_Address__c}"/> 
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: does control goes to your method `remove`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things which are not handled correctly.

1. Your `actionFunction` should have `reRender` attribute. You have used `reRendered`.
2. Create `List<Stud__c>` using getter instead of defining it in Constructor.
3. You are just removing item from list and not deleting it from back-end.

Your code should be:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="remove" action="{!remove}" reRender="dummy2" >
    <apex:param name="arg" value="" assignTo="{!conId}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:outputPanel id="dummy2">
    <apex:pageBlock id="rm">
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!contacts}" var="co">
            <apex:column headerValue="Delete Record">
            <apex:commandLink value="Delete" onClick="remove('{!co.Id}');" /></apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!co.Name__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!co.Email_Address__c}"/> 
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

And your **Controller** should be:

```
public List<Stud__c> contacts { get {
    return new List<Stud__c>([Select Id,Name__c, Email_Address__c from Stud__c]);
}set;}

public String conId{get;set;}
public void remove(){
    integer index = 0;

    Stud__c c = null;
    for(Stud__c con : contacts){
        if(con.Id == conId){
            c = contacts.get(index);
            contacts.remove(index);
            break;
        }
        index ++ ;
    }
    if (c!=null)
        delete c;
   // return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this piece of code

```
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!contacts}" var="co">
          <apex:column headerValue="Delete Record">
          <a href="#" onClick="remove('{!co.Id}');">Delete</a></apex:column>
         <apex:column value="{!co.Name__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!co.Email_Address__c}"/> 
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

into:

```
   <apex:pageblockTable value="{!contacts}" var="co">
          <apex:column headerValue="Delete Record">
          <a href="#" onClick="remove('{!co.Id}'); return false;">Delete</a></apex:column>
         <apex:column value="{!co.Name__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!co.Email_Address__c}"/> 
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

There is a conflict in `actionfunction` event and command button action.

Comment: still it won't work cause OP has not used `reRender` attribute in `actionFunction`.